# Identifying click tags names used by an swf file

Tags: c#, flash, clicktag

How can I read the click tags names used by a flash file?
I'm using C#.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to add more details. What I need is the name of the click tags that is stored inside the file SWF itself. A click tag can be spelled ClickTAG, ClickTag, CLICKTAG, CLickTag54. What's the best way to read the swf and figure out what are the names of the clicktags used?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about [ClickTags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clicktag) you can read the tag from the URL in c#.  Using something like `Page.Request.QueryString`  See the [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx)